# Email always sent successfully (Opencart v3.0.2.0)

Tags: php, email, opencart

I'm having a big problem when configuring OpenCart
I successfully configured the email client for my clients, but when I tried a non-existent mail, it also reported successful delivery.

> Your message has been successfully sent to 4 of 4 recipients!

And when I checked the code in : 
**system / library / mail / mail.php**

```
if ($this->parameter) {         
        mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);            
    } else {        
        mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);  
    }
```

And I found out that no true or false value was returned to me when sending mail.

How do I know which email address my customer has not sent?

Comment: mail function don't know that email id exist or not in your db/system. You have to check first and if exist then only send mail.

Comment: So I can not check whether the email was successfully sent or not?
Although mail does not exist?So if that email exists in the db then it will send and announce success?

Comment: what i want to say is check that given mail-id exist in your database/system. If exist then use mail function otherwise don't use mail function

Comment: My email has been sent to the customer successfully. But I just want to check that if a certain mail client does not exist, it will notify me when sending mail. It is not always successful, even if it does not exist.

Comment: `mail()` function can't do that.Because there is nothing like not-exist for the function itself.

Comment: Can I do this?
`if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter)) {
    return true;
   }
   else {
    return false;
   }`

Comment: Can I get error 550 (email does not exist) in smtp.php?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get notify for the unsuccessful email. You can check the email logs for it which will clarify whether email has been sent or not.

You will need to check logs of the email address where you get the reply from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just worried that when there are too many emails that do not exist, my log of the email address will be a lot.

Comment: Can I get error 550 (email does not exist) in smtp.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this

```
if ($this->parameter) {         
       return mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);            
    } else {        
       return mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);  
    }
}
```

As the php mail function returns true or false.  However, if you update your software your changes may be lost, so you keep a log of all small changes you make.